After Effects Crashes When Running Script via Command Line (-r), Works Fine from Interface
I’ve been facing an issue with running a command line script in After Effects and could really use some help.
Here’s the command I’m using:
"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects 2024/Support Files/afterfx.exe" -r "C:/Scripts/generated_script.jsx"

The goal is to automate the process of copying a project (ProjetA.aep), modifying some text via a JSON file, and saving it under a new name (ProjetB.aep) in a different folder.
When I run the script directly from the After Effects interface, everything works perfectly. However, when I try to run it via the command line:

If After Effects is not already running, it crashes.
If After Effects is already open, it doesn’t crash, but the script doesn’t execute either.

I’ve also tried running very simple scripts (just an alert message, for example), but the same issue persists.
Additional details:

I’m running the command as an administrator.
I’m working through Remote Desktop.
UAC (User Account Control) is disabled.

How to resolve this issue?
What I tried:
Running the script via the After Effects interface: This works perfectly—After Effects opens the project, modifies the text via the JSON file, and saves the new project file as expected.
Running the same script via the command line using the -r flag:
If After Effects is not running, it opens After Effects but then crashes.
If After Effects is already open, it doesn’t crash, but the script doesn’t execute (nothing happens).
Testing with a simple script (just an alert message) to rule out complex issues with the JSON or project modification. Even with this basic script, the same issue occurs: crashing if After Effects is closed, and no execution if it's already open.
What I was expecting:
I was expecting After Effects to open (if not already running), execute the script, modify the text in the .aep file based on the JSON data, and save the new file into the specified directory. Basically, I expected the same behavior I see when running the script manually through the interface.

I'm on the same boat as you (although my script closes After Effects once finished) and the only way I have managed to make it work is to have the script that I want to run on the startup folder as a .JSX (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2024\Support Files\Scripts\Startup\generated_script.jsx) and then run a script (in my case either the full script or even only a close After Effects script) and then it works as intended.
I suspect it's an issue with After Effects calling the script too early, and even adding delays inside the script won't help.

Found a solution that works for me, at least. Try running this command on your console:
"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects 2024/Support Files/afterfx.exe" -s "$.evalFile("C:\Scripts\generated_script.jsx")"

Please do not add such info in the comments; edit & update your post instead.
